# Creating a two-player memory matching game in python

Tags: python, matrix, grid

I am working on a two-player memory matching game in python. The game should have a 6x6 grid with hidden numbers from 1 to 18. The players will specify the row and column for their two guesses, if its a match the player will be rewarded a point. And the same player will continue. If the 2 guesses are not a match, then the next player continues. Each turn the program should ask the player if they want to continue. At the end the program should display the total pairs of each player.

So far this is what I have worked on, I know its not much I would appreciate a little help.

```
x = "▫️️"

answerGrid = [['a  ', 'z  ', 'p  ', 'i  ', 'z  ', 'o  '],
              ['x  ', 'x  ', 'f  ', 'l  ', 'u  ', 'h  '],
              ['d  ', 'd  ', 'l  ', 'o  ', 'p  ', 'f  '],
              ['c  ', 'i  ', 'm  ', 'a  ', 'h  ', 'g  '],
              ['y  ', 'u  ', 's  ', 'b  ', 'y  ', 'k  '],
              ['g  ', 'm  ', 'c  ', 'k  ', 's  ', 'b  ']]

blankGrid = [[x, x, x, x, x, x],
             [x, x, x, x, x, x],
             [x, x, x, x, x, x],
             [x, x, x, x, x, x],
             [x, x, x, x, x, x],
             [x, x, x, x, x, x]]

guesses = 0
guess1 = "  "
guess2 = "  "
option = 0
emptySpaces = 0
correctGuesses = []
rowsAvailable = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
colsAvailable = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
cont = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would maybe start by making the grid easy to work with. Take a look at this code for example:

```
grid_width = 6
grid_height = 6
grid_dimensions_product = (grid_width * grid_height)

if grid_dimensions_product % 2 != 0:
    raise ValueError("Product of grid dimensions must be divisible by two!")

number_of_pairs = grid_dimensions_product // 2

print(f"For a {grid_width}x{grid_height} grid, you'll have {number_of_pairs} pairs.")
```

Output:

```
For a 6x6 grid, you'll have 18 pairs.
```

With a setup like this, we can change the dimensions of our grid anytime we want to introduce more variety into the game. The number of pairs will be calculated on the fly, which is desirable since we don't like hardcoding things. However, the grid dimensions must always multiply together to yield a product which is divisible by two. This is a requirement because we could otherwise end up with not enough pairs (a position on the grid which doesn't have a matching pair) - for example, a 5 x 5 grid would have 12 pairs, so only 24 numbers in total. That's why the if-statement is there. Here is the same code again, but with invalid grid dimensions:

```
grid_width = 5
grid_height = 5
grid_dimensions_product = (grid_width * grid_height)

if grid_dimensions_product % 2 != 0:
    raise ValueError("Product of grid dimensions must be divisible by two!")

number_of_pairs = grid_dimensions_product // 2

print(f"For a {grid_width}x{grid_height} grid, you'll have {number_of_pairs} pairs.")
```

Output:

```
ValueError: Product of grid dimensions must be divisible by two!
```

Once we have our `number_of_pairs`, we can generate a list of hidden numbers, which we will later use to populate our grid:

```
hidden_numbers = list(range(1, number_of_pairs + 1)) * 2
print(hidden_numbers)
```

Remember, `range` is exclusive. If we want the numbers 1-18 inclusive, we have to add a +1 to the exclusive end of our range. We turn the range into a list and multiply the list by two, so that we get the numbers 1-18, twice:

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

Now, we'll have to shuffle the hidden numbers. At the top of your code, write:

```
from random import shuffle
```

To import the `shuffle` function. It takes a list as an argument and shuffles its contents in place.

```
hidden_numbers = list(range(1, number_of_pairs + 1)) * 2
shuffle(hidden_numbers)

hidden_number_iter = iter(hidden_numbers)

grid = []

# Generate the grid
for y in range(grid_height):
    row = [next(hidden_number_iter) for x in range(grid_width)]
    grid.append(row)

# Print the grid
for y in range(grid_height):
    print(grid[y])
```

After shuffling, we create an iterator of our `hidden_numbers` list. This will allow us to easily grab the "next" hidden number from our shuffled list. If you're not familiar with iterators, here's a quick example of iterator behavior:

```
>>> my_list = ["A", "B", "C"]
>>> my_list_iterator = iter(my_list)
>>> next(my_list_iterator)
'A'
>>> next(my_list_iterator)
'B'
>>> next(my_list_iterator)
'C'
>>> next(my_list_iterator)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    next(my_list_iterator)
StopIteration
>>>
```

When we finally print our grid, it will look something like this:

```
[9, 1, 2, 14, 18, 8]
[15, 4, 3, 16, 16, 2]
[12, 11, 6, 1, 17, 13]
[17, 7, 5, 5, 13, 4]
[6, 12, 10, 14, 18, 7]
[3, 15, 10, 9, 11, 8]
```

Each time you restart the script, your list of hidden numbers will appear in a different order. Here's the entire script once more:

```
from random import shuffle

grid_width = 6
grid_height = 6
grid_dimensions_product = (grid_width * grid_height)

if grid_dimensions_product % 2 != 0:
    raise ValueError("Product of grid dimensions must be divisible by two!")

number_of_pairs = grid_dimensions_product // 2

hidden_numbers = list(range(1, number_of_pairs + 1)) * 2
shuffle(hidden_numbers)

hidden_number_iter = iter(hidden_numbers)

grid = []

# Generate the grid
for y in range(grid_height):
    row = [next(hidden_number_iter) for x in range(grid_width)]
    grid.append(row)

# Print the grid
for y in range(grid_height):
    print(grid[y])
```